# Свайпы не работают некоторое время

Tags: c#, unity3d, swipe

> Создаю ранер и когда запускаю игру свайпы не работают примерно 5 секунд, но потом всё отлично работает с чем это может быть связано?

```
public Transform Rocet;
public int speed;
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if ((Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.x)) > Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.y))
    {
        if (eventData.delta.x > 0)
        {
            Rocet.position += Vector3.right *speed ;
        }
        else
        {
            Rocet.position += Vector3.left * speed;
        }
    }
    
         
    
}
```

Comment: Это Unity?.....

Comment: Да на телефоне тоже 5 секунуд примерно не работает, но потом во все стороны свайпаются